# EJB client with Glassfish

Tags: java, glassfish, ejb

I am learning EJB 3 with Glassfish 3. IDE is Eclipse. I want to write a standalone client test application outside of container. I need javaee.jar, appserv-rt.jar to compile. so I copy these jars from Glassfish lib dir, then I realize all files only contains maven pom file.

Questions

1. where to download javaee.jar, appserv-rt.jar with implementation ?
2. how to use maven to download it ?
3. where to downaload ejb maven artifacts ?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are having `Maven` installed, already. And you are also using it in some of your project. So, why not use maven to build your client project as well?

You can check your local `maven` repository for actual `jars`.

In case you are interested in exploring Netbeans, that comes with the first class maven plugin, which is just awesome.

Best place to look for Maven books/tutorials, [Sonatype](http://www.sonatype.com/books/maven-book/).

Answer (score 0):

For Eclipse you just need the plugin m2eclipse via the marked place. For usage without it you have to install Maven from [here](http://maven.apache.org/). Maven will take care of your other questions.